# Finding time difference between columns

Tags: python

I am currently working with a dataset which has two DateTime columns: `ACTUAL_SHIPMENT_DTM` and `SHIPMENT_CONFIRMED_DTM`.

I am trying to find the difference in time between the two columns. I have tried the following code but the output is giving me the time difference of one column based on the rows. Basically I want a new column to be populated with the time difference of (`ACTUAL_SHIPMENT_DTM` - `SHIPMENT_CONFIRMED_DTM`).

```
Golden['Cycle_TIme'] = Golden.groupby('ACTUAL_SHIPMENT_DTM')
['SHIPMENT_CONFIRMED_DTM'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
```

Can anyone see errors in my code or guide me to proper documentation?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be enough information.  What is `Golden`? Please add more information to your question. Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read [mcve] and [ask].  It is always helpful if you include a minimal example of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Lol I underestimated myself and asked a question way too soon. Well if anyone wants to know how to find the time difference between two columns here is my example code. Golden = DataFrame

```
      Golden['Cycle_TIme'] = Golden["SHIPMENT_CONFIRMED_DTM"]-
      Golden["ACTUAL_SHIPMENT_DTM"]
```